# How to stop download the database every time the app runs?

Tags: core-data, swift2

Every time the app runs it downloads the data from the server, how can I stop it from download if the data is already in the device?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        preloadData()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
        }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("CoreDataDemo", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
        }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CoreDataDemo.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)

NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
        }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
        }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - CSV Parser Methods

    func parseCSV (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding) -> [(name:String, detail:String, price: String)]? {

        // Load the CSV file and parse it
        let delimiter = ","
        var items:[(name:String, detail:String, price: String)]?

        do {
            let content = try String(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding: encoding)
            print(content)
            items = []
            let lines:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]

            for line in lines {
                var values:[String] = []
                if line != "" {
                    // For a line with double quotes
                    // we use NSScanner to perform the parsing
                    if line.rangeOfString("\"") != nil {
                        var textToScan:String = line
                        var value:NSString?
                        var textScanner:NSScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                        while textScanner.string != "" {

                            if (textScanner.string as NSString).substringToIndex(1) == "\"" {
                                textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                                textScanner.scanUpToString("\"", intoString: &value)
                                textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                            } else {
                                textScanner.scanUpToString(delimiter, intoString: &value)
                            }

                            // Store the value into the values array
                            values.append(value as! String)

                            // Retrieve the unscanned remainder of the string
                            if textScanner.scanLocation < textScanner.string.characters.count {
                                textToScan = (textScanner.string as NSString).substringFromIndex(textScanner.scanLocation + 1)
                            } else {
                                textToScan = ""
                            }
                            textScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                        }

} else  {
                        values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                    }
                    let item = (name: values[0], detail: values[1], price: values[2])
                    items?.append(item)
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return items
    }

    func preloadData () {

        // Load the data file. For any reasons it can't be loaded, we just return
        guard let remoteURL = NSURL(string: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xB0m95siM2OVRCclRIRXZWZXM/menudata.csv") else {


"https://googledrive.com/host/0ByZhaKOAvtNGTHhXUUpGS3VqZnM/menudata.csv"
  return
        }

        // Remove all the menu items before preloading
        removeData()

        if let items = parseCSV(remoteURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            // Preload the menu items
            for item in items {
                let menuItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MenuItem", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! MenuItem
                menuItem.name = item.name
                menuItem.detail = item.detail
                menuItem.price = (item.price as NSString).doubleValue

                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func removeData () {
        // Remove the existing items
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem")

        do {
            let menuItems = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [MenuItem]
            for menuItem in menuItems {
                managedObjectContext.deleteObject(menuItem)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store a flag or check the number of stored items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always the exact same data, then you can just try to fetch one entity...

ObjC...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (result == nil) {
    // Handle error...
} else if (result.count == 0) {
    // You know you do not have any items, so download
}
```

However, if your server data can change, and it's bulk, then you may want to compute a hash of the data (SHA-1 or similar).  You can store the hash from the last bulk data you downloaded, and ask the server for the current hash value.

If the values are different (or if you have no hash value), then get the data from the server.

If it's incremental, you can use the same hash, or just use a timestamp from the server from the last modification to the server data.  The client can store that.  If they are different, then pull down data since the last timestamp -- (note it does not have to be a timestamp... it could easily just be an incrementing number).

**EDIT**

I have yet to have any reason to learn swift (though you probably should at least learn to read ObjC since the vast majority of all iOS/OSX code is written in ObjC), so this is just a feeble, uncompiled attempt.

In particular, I'm not sure if "let" creates a constant where the variable binding can't be changed, or if it makes it "const" in a C++ sense, where it can't accept mutating methods, so setting the fetchLimit may or may not work.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1        
do {
    let result = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    // I assume this code only gets executed if there is no error
    if result.count == 0 {
        // You know you do not have any items, so download
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, The data will not change, there are many errors in this block most probably is because I am using swift2 I will try to figure out the differences, but if you have for swift I appreciate very much :)

Comment: sorry for delay works very well, the only change I made in your code was "context" -> managedObjectContext (swift2). Thank as lot.